# Show forum but hide topics inside

Tags: forum, phpbb, phpbb3

i have a question to ask regarding PHPBB:
Is it possible to show a forum but keep all the topics inside hidden to all the non authorized?

EG.
A section of a board is for Admins and Moderators discussions. There are two forums: "Moderator discussions" and "Admin discussion". How it is possible to show the "Admin discussion" forum to the moderators without being able to read the topics inside. So in short moderators must know that there is an Admin forum but they cannot read what's inside.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible with the "Group forum permissions". Quite few steps so I broke it down for you to make it easier to follow:

**1)** Login into ACP (Admin Control Panel) navigate to (Tabbed menu):
"Users and Groups" (then left menu column) "Groups" and click "Group forum permissions".

**2)** From the main selector "Group forum permissions" select the "guests" group (you might need to do the same for any groups you want to change this behavior) now submit and select the category and forum and submit again.

**3)** Now click on "Advanced Permission" then from the tabbed menu there click on "Actions" and now look for "Can see forum" and set it to "yes".

Now the guests users can see the category but not the topics in it. Repeat the same steps with any other groups you would like to achieve the same.

You can see a demo here: [FLATBOOTS Theme - live preview](https://themeforest.net/item/flatboots-phpbb-32-highperformance-and-creative-modern-forum-for-phpbb/8536771)

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir!
Sometimes PHPBB has some trivial nested menus/actions to do the job...

Comment: indeed. many steps and can get confusing, especially the permissions... You can checkout http://sitesplat.com for tutorials, premium extensions, themes etc. Tons of goodies there for phpBB admins.